# Table resize and shifting of adjacent tables

Tags: excel, vba, resize

I have a vba code that populates the excel tables across the worksheets in a workbook. 
Most of the work Worksheets have single table. The code works fine and tables expand and contract based on the fetched data columns and rows.

One of the worksheets have two adjacent tables. I want to expand the 1st table in such a way that the second table gets pushed out(shift right) to accommodate the data of the 1st table. Also if the data fetched has lesser columns then the second table should shift left. So that both tables are always adjacent to each other.

Below is the code snippet

```
'''''''''Build and execute the Query'''''''''''
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & bdvName
' MsgBox sqlQuery
rs.Open sqlQuery, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    rs.Close
    Exit Sub
End If

''''''''''''Copy data into the excel sheet ''''''''''''''''
With mySheet.ListObjects(1)
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

    Call .Range(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset(rs)
    Call .Resize(mySheet.UsedRange)
End With

'If rs.EOF = False Then
 '   mySheet.Range("A11").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.MoveFirst
    'wsMatch.Range("A8").CopyFromRecordset rs
    With wsMatch.ListObjects(1)
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

    Call .Range(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset(rs)
    Call .Resize(mySheet.UsedRange)
End With
```

Attaching the scenarios.

[image: Scenarios for the table shifting]

Comment: What specifically is the problem though?  You don't show any code so it's difficult to know what the real question is here.

Comment: There are two problems: 1) If the data fetched from the database has more number of columns than the defined in the initial table size. The data overflows to the 2nd adjacent table instead of pushing the adjacent table to the right 2) If the data size is less than the defined table size, the code  shrinks the 1st table leaving gap between 1st and the 2nd adjacent table.. I am very new to vba coding and not able to find a way to move tables relative to the other table.

Comment: Without any idea of exactly how you're populating your tables the best I could suggest would be to insert a bunch of columns between your two tables before the update, then remove the "extra" ones when you're done.

Comment: I want to add columns to the worksheet next to table1 based on the size of the fetched data (number of fetched columns from the database  is greater than current table size) so that the table1 can expand while keeping table2 adjacent to the table1. 2) I want to delete worksheet columns before table 2 so that table1 can contract to match the fetched columns

Comment: That sounds about right and if you *show your existing code* (last hint! - see "without knowing exactly how you're populating your tables") I'm sure someone may be able to help.